# Поиск по БД using entityframework in mvc project

Tags: c#, база-данных, веб-программирование

Есть таблица в базе данных для нее есть контроллер

```
namespace MoveApplication.Controllers
{
    public class CostumersController : Controller
    {
        private MoviesDBEntities db = new MoviesDBEntities();

        // GET: Costumers
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var costumer = db.Costumers.Include(e => e.CostumerID);
            return View(db.Costumers.ToList());
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string FirstName, Costumers costumers)
        {
            var costumer = db.Costumers.ToList().Where(p=>p.FirstName.StartsWith(FirstName));
            return View(db.Costumers);
        }
        // GET: Costumers/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Costumers costumers = db.Costumers.Find(id);
            if (costumers == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(costumers);
        }
```

во вью прописал

```
<form id="formSearch" method="post">
    <div class="row" id="SearchBox">
        <div class="col-md-1"> Costumer Name</div>
        <div class="col-md-2"><input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-1"><input type="submit" id="submitsearch" name="Search" /></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Почему-то не ищет. Все делал по этой инструкции https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka59HciHBRo&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны создать класс контенкста данных, который наследуется от System.Data.Entity.DbContext, в котором через DbSet присвоить все сущности.
Кроме того, в зависимости от подхода работы с БД (Code first/Model first) вы должны прописать строку подключения в web.config такого примера для Windows Server 2014 и старше:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\MyDb.mdf';Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Только после этого создав экземпляр вышего контекса в контроллере вы можете обратиться к нему, пример:

```
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
    MyContext db = new MyContext();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<User> Users = db.Users;
        ViewBag.Users = users;
        return View();
    }
}
```